# Distinguish between email address and IRI

Tags: uri, ip-address, email-address, iri

I have a string that can contain either an email address or an IRI (internationalized URI). The strings do not contain additional surrounding whitespace or any HTTP linefolding characters. Moreover they do not contain any elements marked as "obsolete" in their corresponding specifications. I need a simple way to distinguish which of these things the string contains.

I'm looking at what I believe to be the latest respective specifications: [RFC 5322 § 3.4.1. Addr-Spec Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) for emails, and [RFC 3987 § 2.2. ABNF for IRI References and IRIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-2.2) for IRIs. I've come up with the following algorithm, with explanations in parentheses:

1. If the string begins with a quote `"` character, it is an email address. (Email address `local-part` may be a quoted string, but an IRI `scheme` may not.)
2. Otherwise find the first at `@` sign or colon `:` character.

   - If the character encountered is an at `@` sign, the string contains an email address.
   - Otherwise, if it is a colon `:` character, the string contains an IRI.

Is that approach correct? Is there another simpler approach? Lastly for bonus, how would I expand this algorithm to also distinguish those two things from an IP address (including both IPv4 and IPv6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the rules as specified are correct and fast to determine the type (email or IRI). To extend this to IP addresses their corresponding grammar should be added: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00.

So then your rules could be extended to:

Rules: (I assumed well formed input)

- First char `"` => email
- First char `:` => IpV6 (because an IRI the scheme has to contain at least one char)
- First of `:` or `@`

  - `@` => email
  - `:` =>

    - If it does not match the grammar for IpV6 => IRI
    - Otherwise: ambiguous, also in the grammar, some options

      1. Use as IpV6 => it will be valid, likely to be the thing intended
      2. Use it as IRI => the first part (before the ':') will be a scheme the later part will be one 'segment' in the protocol

         - So `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` will lead to scheme `ffff` and 'segment' `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`
         - I would find this situation very unlikely
      3. Raise an exception, depending on the environment this could be a valid option
  - Both not in the string => IpV4

```
ipchar := hex / ':'
hex    := [0-9A-Fa-f]
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight into IP addresses. But wouldn't your rules be ambiguous for IRIs? Couldn't an IRI also have four or more colon characters?

Comment: I guess IRIs couold also contain 4 or more colons, that is why I added the comment to parse the IpV6, because that is much easier to parse than IRIs and so if it succeeds in parsing an IpV6 it can be considered an IpV6 otherwise it would be an IRI.

Comment: But I don't understand this part of your logic: what part of succeeding in parsing as an IpV6 prevents it from being an IRI?

Comment: On basis of the grammer of the IRI as presented in your link an IpV6 could also be interpreted as an IRI. But if it is a valid IpV6 I would assume it is more likely to be an IpV6 than an IRI. But that assumption is totally dependent on the thing you want to do with your algorithm.

Comment: The whole point of this question was to find an easy way to distinguish with 100% certainty without assuming. The question was whether the rules I indicated gave a certain result, not a probability. For IpV6 addresses the answer may be that the grammars allow strings that match both IRI and IpV6 productions. But for my purposes assumptions and probabilities are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I worked myself throught the grammars one more time and I think I found the rules to determine if it is an IpV6 or not. If you are interested I could try and rework the english in my answer to some kind of grammar to be able to prove my correctness.

Comment: I reworked it to a more mathematical notation and found that there is indeed in the grammar ambiguity. (when both IpV6 and IRI are to be expected)

Comment: This wasn't a solution for the IP address part, but the main thing was that I needed another set of eyes to look at this and tell me if I made any mistakes. So I awarded you the bounty, @Douwe. Thanks. If you could just double check the email vs IRI part (if you haven't already) and make sure I didn't mess up on that, I would appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay sorry I could not give a definitive answer for the IP address part. But I double checked your rules and they are complete and valid.